# "The real us", or "the realest thing of us" or "the real self of us"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'd want to use the adjective "real" for pronoun "us"
Am I right in this way?

"The real us", or "the realest thing of us" or "the real self of us"?

Comment: Please, give us some context...

Comment: about special opinion in a philosophical context ...oh the relation of mind and body for example